# AngularJS form is not submitting with ng-click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I started creating an AngularJS form, other parts of my AngularJS app are working just fine.

**html file looks like this**

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="submitForm()">

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="fullName">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fullName" name="fullName" class="form-control"
           ng-model="employee.fullName" />
</div>


<div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"
           ng-click="submitForm()" />
</div>
</form>
```

**controller**

```
  var QuestionEditController = function ($location, questionService, $env) {

    var employee = {};

    console.log('pre employee', employee);  // this works

    submitForm = function () {

        console.log('employee', employee);  // clicking on submit button does not make it in here

    };
```

**I'm using ui-router and that looks like this**

```
     .state("editquestion",
            {
                url: "/editquestion",
                templateUrl: viewBase + "questionEdit.html",
                controller: "QuestionEditController",
                controllerAs: "vm"
            });

};
```

I do have a simple directive that does simply display the html code template , but I cannot see how that would cause a problem, what am I doing wrong?

**Update**

Ok,  the issue was indeed the ng-click.

However,  I'm wondering if i'm creating more of a "mess"  look at what else i added  ( vm. )  in front of even the submitForm

**New HTML**

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="vm.submitForm()">

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="fullName">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fullName" name="fullName" class="form-control"
           ng-model="vm.employee.fullName" />
</div>


<div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"/>
</div>
</form>
```

**Controller updated**

```
var QuestionEditController = function ($location, questionService, $env) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.employee = {};

    console.log('pre employee', vm.employee);

    vm.submitForm = function () {

        console.log('employee', vm.employee);

    };

};
```

**Is what I'm doing needed , some of it or none of it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) you don't need a `ng-click`directive to fire `ng-submit`. Just use a input of `type="submit"` inside your form element and you will be fine. `ng-submit` will be fired by pressing the submit button inside your form.

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="vm.submitForm()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fullName">Name</label>
        <input type="text" 
               id="fullName" 
               name="fullName" 
               class="form-control" 
               ng-model="vm.employee.fullName" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
        <input type="submit" 
               class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

---

Ensure your submit function is a controller based or scope based function so it's able to get called by the view:

```
var QuestionEditController = function ($location, questionService, $env) {
    var vm = this
    vm.employee = {};
    vm.submitForm = function () {
        console.log('employee', employee);  
    };
};
```

Comment: I did go around putting  vm.submitForm   ,  vm.employee   etc..    that did not work until i removed the `ngclick`   i guess i'm not sure what,  because i'm watching a angular video  ( however it was with $scope  before controller as  etc..

Comment: I'm not using $scope , and controller as fixes that for a good reason ( this keyword, angular 2 , ES 2015 etc.. $scope injection has become a bad practice    -      Ok,  I see you fixed   thx

Answer (score 1):

Make your function scope in order to access from the form.

remove the `ng-click` also since you are using `ng-submit` like @lin mentioned

```
 $scope.submitForm = function () {
   console.log('employee', employee); 
};
```

Updated

if you are not using scope in the controller then assign `this` to variable and use controller as in html

`ng-controller="ctrl as vm"`

Demo

```js
var QuestionEditController = function ($scope) {
    var vm  = this
    vm.employee = {};

    console.log('pre employee', vm.employee);  // this works

    vm.submitForm = function () {
        console.log('employee', vm.employee); 
    }; 
   }
    
    angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",QuestionEditController)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
 <form role="form" ng-submit="vm.submitForm()">

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fullName">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fullName" name="fullName" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.employee.fullName" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: @Jeremy Miller then use controller as in the html `ng-controller="ctrl as vm"` check the demo again

Comment: I'm not using $scope , and controller as fixes that for a good reason ( this keyword,  angular 2 , ES 2015  etc..     $scope injection has become a bad practice

Answer (score 1):

```
          <html lang="en" ng-app="demo">
          <head>
          <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
           <link rel="stylesheet" 

   href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script>
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
  <script 
     src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
 </script>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module("demo",[])
        .controller("cc",function($scope){
            $scope.students = 
 ["student1","student2","student3","student4","student5","student6","student7","student8"]
        })


    </script>

<body>

        <div class="container"></div>
       <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 "><strong> Batch 1</strong> </div>

     <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 pull-right" > <strong> Venu 4</strong>
 </div>


 </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
   <!-- Default panel contents -->
   <div class="panel-heading"><strong>Name</strong></div>


  </div>

  <!-- List group -->
        <div ng-controller="cc">
        <ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="student in students">
        <li class="list-group-item">{{student}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This doesnt solve the problem at all. It's a kind of a non sense answer.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow please read this section carefully http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

No need to handle ng-click event to submit form. Use type="submit"

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="vm.submitForm()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fullName">Name</label>
        <input type="text" 
               id="fullName" 
               name="fullName" 
               class="form-control" 
               ng-model="vm.employee.fullName" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
        <input type="submit" 
               class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```